# should I assign a =_variable to a UIIButton or UILabel property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

hello a noob question here.

during my studies I was repeatedly instructed to always specify a =_propertyName variable when @synthesize-ing a @property

so for example for

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

I would do

```
@synthesize myTimer = _myTimer;
```

now my question is. does this have to be done for IB properties as well ?
such as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

do I just do here:

```
@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize myButton;
```

or:

```
@synthesize myLabel=  _myLabel;
@synthesize myButton = _myButton;
```

Now I can see, why this is useful for something like an NSArray, or NSString or BOOL where you're actually storing some values, but I am not sure how/if this logic applies to UIButtons, UILabels and similar. Thank you for any pointers (no put intended)

Comment: It's just a matter of naming convention. Prefixing your ivars in a uniform manner makes your code more readable, because you can always tell an ivar from a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of preference. There is a difference that you should keep in mind, however, as far as scope. For example, if you write your synthesizer like this,

```
@synthesize myTime = _myTime;
```

And you are within the scope of an instance method of the class, for example, `-(void)setTime:(id)myTime;`, there is a difference between calling,

```
self.myTime = newTime;
```

And,

```
myTime = newTime;
```

It becomes clear that the first changes the instance variable of your object, and that the second reassigns the `myTime` local variable passed in as an argument to the method `setTime:`, which is something you usually don't want to do. However, if you synthesized your instance variable like this,

```
@syntehsize myTime;
```

It is a little more confusing what would happen with this assignment,

```
myTime = newTime;
```

This actually reassigns the local variable, and may not be what you intended. So in naming your variables it is good to stick to conventions and try to avoid confusion. That is why it is my personal preference to assign the underscore and always set instance variables by calling them attached to `self`.

Comment: cool, thanks for the great explanation. so you do =_variable for @synthesize-es ?  even for UIButtons, UILabels and other IBOutlets ?

Comment: Yes, for all instance variables.

Comment: I'll do the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of conventions. Try to stick with one convention, this is not only true for variable names, it is true for everything you program.

Comment: I See. So I am only deciding whether the object will be stored in object or _object named variable. So there is no factual difference in the two variables (except for the name) ?

Comment: You only change the name of how you access this button.

Comment: I See. So it's really about a coding style only. I Get it now.

Answer (score 0):

> during my studies I was repeatedly instructed to always specify a =_propertyName variable when @synthesize-ing a @property

that's just a matter of preference. some people prefer `@synthesize myTimer;`, some people have other preferences…

> now my question is. does this have to be done for IB properties as well ?

you must synthesize or define the methods in some form. beyond that, just choose one convention and stick with it!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the "_var" serves to better differentiate between a getter/setter and its actual related variable.

if

```
@Synthesize myTimer = _myTimer;
```

is employed. you will be reminded every time whether you are using the setter/getter or directly accessing the variable.

e.g. if the @Synthesize is used,then

```
self.myTimer = anotherTimer;
```

will be the same as

```
[self setMyTimer(anotherTimer)];
```

meanwhile

```
_myTimer = anotherTimer;
```

is merely assigning the variable;

yes,it's a matter of convention, but if you want to differentiate between calling a setter/getter and directly accessing the variable, the "_var" should be used. it not, it doesn't really matter.